# Find the total length of the cloth Mr. X and Mr. Y had in the beginning

Tags: arithmetic, problem-solving

```
Mr. X had 24 m more clothes than Mr. Y. 
Mr. X used 12.8 m of cloth whereas Mr. Y used 11.9 m of cloth everyday.
When Mr. X finished all the cloth he had, Mr. Y was still left with 6.60 m of cloth.

Find the total length of the cloth Mr. X and Mr. Y had in the beginning ?
```

**My attempt**

**----------------------**

Let Mr. Y had K meters of cloth in the beginning.
Then Mr. X had (K+24)  meters of cloth in the beginning.

Mr. Y use (K-11.9) m of cloth everyday.
Mr. X use (K+24 -12.8) m of cloth everyday.

As per the question,

K-11.9 m = 6.60 m (since, Mr. Y was still left with 6.60 m of cloth)

or K = 18.50 meter

i.e. Mr.Y had 18.50 meter of cloth in the beginning.

So, Mr. X had K+24m -12.8 m = 18.5 m + 24m - 12.8m = 29.7 meter

Total length of the cloth Mr. X and Mr. Y had in the beginning = **29.7 meter + 18.50 meter = 48.2 meter**

> But the answer given is 846.4 meter.

Please help to understand what is wrong in my approach.

Comment: The $24m$ extra cloth which Mr X has is not a part of the rate of usage, which is measured in the different units of metres per day (rather than metres). Checking the units of quantities is one way to pick up errors in your equations - since an equation only makes sense (and remains true when the scale of units changes eg to centimetres per second, which is also a rate of usage) if you are equating quantities with the same physical/temporal dimensions.

Comment: with the length of cloth they use in a day and the difference they have in the length of cloth at the beginning and at the end, it is clear that it is not possible in a day. Here is one way to look at it. Everyday $X$ uses $0.9$ meter more cloth than $Y$. In the beginning $X$ has $24$ meter more than $Y$ but in the end has $6.6$ less. So dividing $(24 - (-6.6))$ by $0.9$ should give you number of days required. Then the length of cloth in the beginning is cloth used + cloth left. Cloth used is number of days multiplied by $(12.8+11.9)$ and length of cloth left is $6.6$.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, your approach is wrong. In the problem it has not been stated that both men finish their cloth by the end of the first day. That has to be calculated. Here's what you should do.
Let Mr.Y have $x$ unit long cloth, then Mr.X has $x+24$ units. Now, let Mr.X finish his cloth on the $t^{th}$ day. Then, we have equations:
$$x+24-12.8t=0$$
$$x-11.9t=6.6$$
Solve these two equations, you'll get your answer.